# Countdown Timer Error in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, countdowntimer

I Searched it but any Solution Couldn't solve my problem.
I'm implementing a timer in a fragment but my app stops working showing an error.

This is the working of my app.
when user clicks the start button it takes the user to the next activity where fragments are shown in a container(RelativeLayout). I've implemented the Count CountDownTimer function in the fragment. Fragment was working perfectly before the CountDownTimer function.

Any Help?
Here is the code.

Start.java

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

Fragment frag = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    frag = new BlankFragment1();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,frag);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();





    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
}

public void start(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Start.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

BlankFragment1.java

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BlankFragment1 extends Fragment {


public BlankFragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


Fragment frag = null;
TextView tv;
View root;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    tv = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.timer1);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }

    }.start();



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment1, container,    false);
}

}
```

Error Log

```
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample, PID: 28970
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample/com.example.sheikhspc.timerexamp le.Start}: 
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method  'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object  reference

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.sheikhspc.timerexample.BlankFragment1.onCreateView(BlankFragment1.java:46)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6025)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Post here the error you get.

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: Question Updated with error log

Comment: Please post the rest of the stack trace.

Comment: Updated Again the Question again

Comment: Theres no view inflated on onCreateView prior to calling findViewById

Comment: Your variable "root" is null here and it is giving NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OnCreateView

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment1, null);
```

and then find the items by `v.findViewById` and return the inflated`View`

```
return v;
```

Or you can assign the layout to root by

```
root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment1, null);

tv = (TextView) root.findViewById(...);
// other implementations 

return root;
```

Comment: @Adnan Sheikh Hope it helped

Comment: Than you. Yup It helped.

Comment: it is Accepted :)